# Android global click events

Tags: android, android-layout

hi friends i am have the activity like the below

top bar which consist of

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|Back|Title Text|date select|
-----------------------------
```

middle space is for list of items to display at run time

bottom bar

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|Home|Region|Account|Exit|
--------------------------
```

there are about seven screens are there for all screens above one is the layout for all xml layouts.So i want to add click handlers for all top and bottom bars.So how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add an `OnClickListner` to your `activity` and depending on which `view` received the event, display the corresponding activity.
For instance, you can make your `activity` to implement `OnClickListener`

```
backView.setOnClickListener(this);
titleView.setOnClickListener(this);
...
exitView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and then in the `onClick` method, depending on the view that received the click you perform what you need to perform.

I hope this helps